# php process upload with ajax or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have the form and uploading images which works fine i want to process it through ajax or javascript. how can i adjust my code with javascript so it will not refresh the page and will just print a message UPLOADED Successfully. any help will be highly appreciated.
my code is below:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='upload.php'>
<input name="file" type="file" size="20" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**my JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});
</script>
```

**upload.php:**

```
<?php

function uploadFile ($file_field = null, $check_image = false, $random_name = false) {

  //Config Section    
  //Set file upload path
  $path = 'uploads/'; //with trailing slash
  //Set max file size in bytes
  $max_size = 1000000;
  //Set default file extension whitelist
  $whitelist_ext = array('jpg','png','gif');
  //Set default file type whitelist
  $whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif');

  //The Validation
  // Create an array to hold any output
  $out = array('error'=>null);

  if (!$file_field) {
    $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid form field name";           
  }

  if (!$path) {
    $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid upload path";               
  }

  if (count($out['error'])>0) {
    return $out;
  }

  //Make sure that there is a file
  if((!empty($_FILES[$file_field])) && ($_FILES[$file_field]['error'] == 0)) {

    // Get filename
    $file_info = pathinfo($_FILES[$file_field]['name']);
    $name = $file_info['filename'];
    $ext = $file_info['extension'];

    //Check file has the right extension           
    if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist_ext)) {
      $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Extension";
    }

    //Check that the file is of the right type
    if (!in_array($_FILES[$file_field]["type"], $whitelist_type)) {
      $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Type";
    }

    //Check that the file is not too big
    if ($_FILES[$file_field]["size"] > $max_size) {
      $out['error'][] = "File is too big";
    }

    //If $check image is set as true
    if ($check_image) {
      if (!getimagesize($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'])) {
        $out['error'][] = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
      }
    }

    //Create full filename including path
    if ($random_name) {
      // Generate random filename
      $tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

      if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
        $out['error'][] = "File must have a name";
      }     
      $newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;                                
    } else {
        $newname = $name.'.'.$ext;
    }

    //Check if file already exists on server
    if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
      $out['error'][] = "A file with this name already exists";
    }

    if (count($out['error'])>0) {
      //The file has not correctly validated
      return $out;
    } 

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {
      //Success
      $out['filepath'] = $path;
      $out['filename'] = $newname;
      return $out;
    } else {
      $out['error'][] = "Server Error!";
    }

  } else {
    $out['error'][] = "No file uploaded";
    return $out;
  }      
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $file = uploadFile('file', true, true);
  if (is_array($file['error'])) {
    $message = '';
    foreach ($file['error'] as $msg) {
      $message .= '<p>'.$msg.'</p>';    
    }
  } else {
    $message = "File uploaded successfully";
  }
  echo $message;
}
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: Uploading via ajax is a little more complicated. Check out this tutorial. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax

Comment: can anyone adjust according to my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the form and uploading images which works fine i want to process it through ajax or javascript. how can i adjust my code with javascript so it will not refresh the page and will just print a message UPLOADED Successfully.
**I tried alot for my question and atlast i am succeeded. the answer is below:**

**HTML**

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax-upload.js"></script>

<form id="frmUpload" action="" method="POST" name="default" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="img-upload">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="user-image" required />
<div class="img-preview"></div>
<div class="upload-msg"></div>
</div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Image Or Audio File" class="btn btn-primary">   
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="btn">
    </div>
</form>
```

**ajax-upload.js**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#frmUpload").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".upload-msg").text('Loading...');    
        $.ajax({
            url: "process.php",        // Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
            contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
            cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
            success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {
                $(".upload-msg").html(data);
            }
        });
    }


));

// Function to preview image after validation

$("#file").change(function() {
    $(".upload-msg").empty(); 
    var file = this.files[0];
    var imagefile = file.type;
    var imageTypes= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg","image/gif"];
        if(imageTypes.indexOf(imagefile) == -1)
        {
            $(".upload-msg").html("<span class='msg-error'>Please Select A valid Image File</span><br /><span>Only jpeg, jpg and png Images type allowed</span>");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e){
                $(".img-preview").html('<img src="' + e.target.result + '" />');                
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    }); 
});
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
function uploadFile ($file_field = null, $check_image = false, $random_name = false) {

  //Config Section    
  //Set file upload path
  $path = 'uploads/'; //with trailing slash
  //Set max file size in bytes
  $max_size = 1000000;
  //Set default file extension whitelist
  $whitelist_ext = array('jpg','png','gif');
  //Set default file type whitelist
  $whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif');

  //The Validation
  // Create an array to hold any output
  $out = array('error'=>null);

  if (!$file_field) {
    $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid form field name";           
  }

  if (!$path) {
    $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid upload path";               
  }

  if (count($out['error'])>0) {
    return $out;
  }

  //Make sure that there is a file
  if((!empty($_FILES[$file_field])) && ($_FILES[$file_field]['error'] == 0)) {

    // Get filename
    $file_info = pathinfo($_FILES[$file_field]['name']);
    $name = $file_info['filename'];
    $ext = $file_info['extension'];

    //Check file has the right extension           
    if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist_ext)) {
      $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Extension";
    }

    //Check that the file is of the right type
    if (!in_array($_FILES[$file_field]["type"], $whitelist_type)) {
      $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Type";
    }

    //Check that the file is not too big
    if ($_FILES[$file_field]["size"] > $max_size) {
      $out['error'][] = "File is too big";
    }

    //If $check image is set as true
    if ($check_image) {
      if (!getimagesize($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'])) {
        $out['error'][] = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
      }
    }

    //Create full filename including path
    if ($random_name) {
      // Generate random filename
      $tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

      if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
        $out['error'][] = "File must have a name";
      }     
      $newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;                                
    } else {
        $newname = $name.'.'.$ext;
    }

    //Check if file already exists on server
    if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
      $out['error'][] = "A file with this name already exists";
    }

    if (count($out['error'])>0) {
      //The file has not correctly validated
      return $out;
    } 

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {
      //Success
      $out['filepath'] = $path;
      $out['filename'] = $newname;
      return $out;
    } else {
      $out['error'][] = "Server Error!";
    }

  } else {
    $out['error'][] = "No file uploaded";
    return $out;
  }      
}
?>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_FILES["file"]["type"])){
  $file = uploadFile('file', true, true);
  if (is_array($file['error'])) {
    $message = '';
    foreach ($file['error'] as $msg) {
      $message .= '<p>'.$msg.'</p>';    
    }
  } else {

    $message = "File uploaded successfully";
  }
  echo $message;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `success` property of `$.ajax` which is a function, to execute some code after a successful request.

Exemple :

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function() {
                //Code on successful request
                console.log('UPLOAD Successfully');
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
```

Answer (score -1):

This should good to go assuming you get a proper response from your php,

Too lazy to explain, lol

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            position: relative;
        }
        .loader {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
            display: none;
        }
        .loader.active {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="loader"></div>
    <form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" size="20" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <div class="notice"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDITED**

First make sure there's no error on the console log, 
then check everything on console log

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Capture Form Submit Aaction
        $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function() {

            // Show Loader Div when Button is click
            $('.loader').addClass('active');

            // Add Console Message confirming button is click
            console.log('Start Ajax');

            // Start Ajax Request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',

                // Place URL upload.php url here
                url: 'http://yoursite.com/filesordir/upload.php',

                // Never check your PHP data so I leave this lines below,
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,

                // If ajax response is success
                success: function(data) { 

                    // Hide the Loader Div
                    $('.loader').removeClass('active');

                    // Inser Ajax response to notice div
                    $('.notice').html( data );

                    // Add Console message
                    console.log('Ajax Success');
                }
                error: function( errorThrown ) {

                    // Hide the Loader Div
                    $('.loader').removeClass('active');

                    // Inser error message to notice div
                    $('.notice').html( errorThrown );

                    // Add Console message
                    console.log('Ajax Error');
                }           
           });

        //Edited this, have double ")".
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: it is not uploading. when i select an image then press upload it just reset the selection nothing else

Comment: watch out for this,   var request = {
        'upload': location.href + 'upload.php',
    };

check network and if upload.php indeed run, I assume you are using folder directory and not index.html to open the page in browser

Comment: change this whole line ```url: request.upload,``` to your upload.php url

Comment: well im using index.php and then for process upload.php and uploads/ for the images to be placed. can u please check ? i changed but its just resetting and not uploading

Comment: Place url directly in ajax parameter ```url: 'http://yoursite.com/filesordir/upload.php',``` 

Check Network tab in inspect element and see if your upload.php run after you hit submit button,

Comment: First check if upload.php run in browser network, if it did then check the response, also add console log after button click, while ajax is running, if ajax is success, if ajax is error, you can monitor what everything whats going on :)